# Is it possible to make this GPGPU water example work with different shaped (rectangle, boomerang) planes?

Tags: three.js, gpgpu

This is the example I'm talking about: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_water.html

I have a decent understanding of how it all works because I've successfully added it to a game I'm developing and made quite a few edits and additions to the shaders and js, but **is it even possible to use this type of water for a plane in the shape of a boomerang or anything other than a square AND have the vertices displaced correctly like the example shows**?

My guess would be no because it's using a square texture, but I'm not sure, so I'm hoping someone with more experience with this type of thing could answer that.

Answer (score -1):

In the threebox example you only have to replace the geometry you want to use in the line 388 instead of the PlaneBufferGeometry
[image]

Use this, and you'll get a circle or any other polygon reducing the second param.

```js
const geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(BOUNDS, WIDTH - 1);
```

[image]

[check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/droqw3xb/22/)

Comment: I appreciate you showing me that, but it's exactly what I expected - the water doesn't move correctly.  Thanks again for replying.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, if the answer solver you initial question, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way it will also help other users to know it was right.

Comment: I would, but it didn't answer it completely.  I'll reword my question to make it more specific.

Comment: Well, obviously, I'd want the water to behave like it did in the example if I used a different shaped plane.  When you changed the plane to a circle, it completely broke the vertex animation.